# XSLT if - attribute equals string

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using a `xsl:if` to perform a small condition in a larger `xsl:template` block, and I'd like to test equality of an attribute of the current `xsl:template` matched node.

The following is not working:

```
<xsl:template match="sometag[@type='sometype']">
    ==Sometag==
    <xsl:if test="@something!='hidden'">something</xsl:if>
    <!--a lot of other stuff that I don't want to duplicate by multiplying the xsl:templates-->
<xsl:template>
```

This test seems to be always evaluating to false, maybe I don't have the good syntax?

This XML:

```
<sometag type="sometype" something="visible"/>
<sometag type="sometype" something="hidden"/>
<sometag type="sometype"/>
```

Should give

```
==Sometag==
something...
==Sometag==
==Sometag==
something...
```

Comment: There might be better ways to organize your stylesheet. Please show your XML input file and more XSLT context (if not the entire stylesheet).

Comment: @MathiasMüller I've shown an example XML and what I'd like: the 2nd tag should not get the "something" part printed. And please answer on the `xsl:if` question. My XSLT is much larger and I would like to keep using the `xsl:if` tag, not to reorganize everything.

Comment: Syntax looks fine. Guess this template is not executed or some previous XSLT messes things up. Please provide complete XSLT...

Comment: Does your actual XML have namespaces at all? Also, are you sure you haven't made a typo with your attribute names? The test `<xsl:if test="@something!='hidden'">` will evaluate to false if the attribute "something" does not exist. You might need to do `<xsl:if test="not(@something) or @something!='hidden'">`

Comment: `not(@something = 'hidden')` will also work.  Your current `!=` test asks if the current node _has_ an attribute whose value is _not_ "hidden" whereas the `not` version asks if the current node _does not have_ an attribute whose value _is_ "hidden".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> the 2nd tag should not get the "something" part printed.

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but I'll give it a try.

One of your `sometag` elements does not have a `something` attribute at all. Not having this attribute is entirely different from `@something!='hidden'`. So, the string "something" is not output if the `something` attribute is not present.

Because of this you need to test whether there *is* a `something` attribute before your `xsl:if` condition is evaluated.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<sometag type="sometype" something="visible"/>
<sometag type="sometype" something="hidden"/>
<sometag type="sometype"/>
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="text"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:template match="/root">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sometag[@type='sometype']">
      <xsl:text>==Sometag==</xsl:text>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="@something">
            <xsl:if test="@something!='hidden'">
               <xsl:text>something</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>something</xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT** @Tim C has suggested an even shorter version:

```
 <xsl:template match="sometag[@type='sometype']">
    <xsl:text>==Sometag==</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="@something!='hidden' or not(@something)">
       <xsl:text>something</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
==Sometag==something==Sometag====Sometag==something
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution above (of @Mathias Müller and as suggested by @Tim C) you can even speed up things a little bit using [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for the `or`:

```
<xsl:template match="sometag[@type='sometype']">
    <xsl:text>==Sometag==</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="not(@something) or @something!='hidden'">
        <xsl:text>something</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

If there is no attribute `something` present, then the if-clause already evaluates to `true` and the expression `@something!='hidden'` does not have to be evaluated.